# Universality of artificial neural networks - can they approximate L^2 or L^p space?

Tags: functional-analysis, neural-networks, universal-property

I was reading about the Universal Approximation Theorem for neural networks, and it seems like it is valid only for *continuous* functions defined on the unit hypercube in n-dimensional space: "the space of continuous functions on $I_{m}$ is denoted by $C(I_{m})$"

My question is: is this function space a sub-space of $L^2$? If so, does that mean that ANNs are not really "universal" after all? Can statistics or signal processing techniques approximate such functions that cannot be approximated by ANNs?

Comment: To answer your first question, assuming you imbue $[0, 1]^n$ with the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, any continuous function $f : [0, 1]^n\to \mathbb{R}$ has a compact image (and is therefore bounded by some $M > 0$), and thus if $[0, 1]^n$ is assigned a finite measure $\mu([0, 1]^n)$, $\int_{[0, 1]^n} \lvert f\rvert^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu$ will be bounded above by $M^p\mu([0, 1]^n)$. Therefore, $f\in L^p([0, 1]^n)$.

Comment: To go the other way, note that [the continuous, compactly supported functions are dense in $L^p([0, 1]^n)$.](http://planetmath.org/compactlysupportedcontinuousfunctionsaredenseinlp) Therefore, you could approximate a continuous function that is arbitrarily close to the function of your choice in $L^2([0, 1]^n)$ or $L^p([0, 1]^n)$ for some other $p$.

Comment: Thanks! A follow up question would be whether non-continuous functions can be in $L^2$. Are all functions in $L^2$ necessarily continuous?

Comment: No, functions in $L^2$ are not necessarily continuous. They only have to be square-integrable.